# Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers. Then how to check the convergence of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $$x_n=\dfrac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n+1}+\dfrac{c}{n+2},\hspace{0.5mm}\mbox{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}$$ Decide whether the series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ converges or not.

I am trying to make this sequence as an oscillating seQUence. But ho we can do that?

Comment: Clearly the sequence converges for $a=b=c=0$. And clearly it diverges for $a=1$ and $b=c=0$. So anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $$x_n=\dfrac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n+1}+\dfrac{c}{n+2}=\left(\frac{a}{n}-\frac{a}{n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{c}{n+2}-\frac{c}{n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{a+b+c}{n+1}\right)$$ Note that $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{n}-\frac{a}{n+1}\right)\mbox{ and } \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{c}{n+2}-\frac{c}{n+1}\right)$$ are convergent series while $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{n+1}\right)$$ is a divergent series. Hence the series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ must be divergent.

Comment: I think there are conditions on $a+b+c$ for that last series to be divergent. (ie if $a+b+c=0$ something might happen..)

broad counter example to your statement: let $b=-a$ and $c=0$ then you recover the expression you suggested was convergent (ie $\frac{a}{n}-\frac{a}{n+1}$)